# Why are television shows in Fahrenheit 451 interactive?

Tags: ray-bradbury, fahrenheit-451

In *Fahrenheit 451* by Ray Bradbury, television shows are broadcast with parts missing so that viewers can act the scenes out:

> She didn't look up from her script again. “Well, this is a play comes on the wall-to-wall circuit in ten minutes. They mailed me my part this morning. I sent in some box-tops. They write the script with one part missing. It's a new idea. The home-maker, that's me, is the missing part. When it comes time for the missing lines, they all look at me out of the three walls and I say the lines: Here, for instance, the man says, 'What do you think of this whole idea, Helen?' And he looks at me sitting here centre stage, see? And I say, I say —” She paused and ran her finger under a line in the script. “ 'I think that's fine!' And then they go on with the play until he says, 'Do you agree to that, Helen!' and I say, 'I sure do!' Isn't that fun, Guy?”

What is the meaning of this interactive television show within the novel? What does it show about the society portrayed there?

Comment: Sounds like a 9th grade homework question.

Comment: @Mike: Homework questions are not off topic here — see [this answer on meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/561/3003).

Comment: btw its not a homework question...I was just wondering. Reading the book for fun.

Comment: It seems like a good/interesting question to me.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that the “interaction” was completely fake but intended to create the impression that those in charge had meaningful relationships with the general population. I guess like when politicians seem to wave at a particular area of the crowd or celebrities allow photos. Propaganda to keep everyone engaged and feeling that they are participating.

Comment: Do you have evidence for this impression?